# how to move neo4j server files around safely

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j folder (all of it) in /home/me/Downloads, which is bad. I want to move it to /usr/lib where I'll think it is, but I was wondering if moving the folder after it's installed (and working properly) will cause any of those weird, explainable errors from things installed automatically in bashrc or whatnot. I just unzipped it to Downloads and it's there and working

I also want to rename it. Can this be done safely?

Thank you

Comment: You say “I just unzipped it to Downloads and it’s there and working”, which doesn’t sound that bad, but then you also say “it was the most brutal install I’ve ever done to get it to work”. Unless there’s something brutal about ZIP extraction or there’s some complicating factor you forgot to mention, I don’t see how those two things can coexist.

Comment: I think I completely confused getting it to work with Python to the install, due to installing wrappers I didn't know weren't maintained anymore and whatnot. Excuse me

Comment: getting the server running was easy, I've been working a lot and forgetting stuff

Comment: While on the topic, if you see this, does anyone know of a wrapper besides neomodel that is maintained and also worked for them? It's all new so I'm sure you gotta read the source to fully understand, but curious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move it, as long as you stop neo4j running before you move.

You can also rename the folder, no problem.